# How can I query records having the same timestamp in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I query records having the same timestamp ?  For example , I have 100 records .. 10 records get inserted into MYSQL at a time and the timestamp is recorded as well, each 10 records will have the same timestamp .. How can I build a query that can return the number of records having the same timestamp ???

Inserting the number of same timestamp from this join query

```
"SELECT DISTINCT question_id, question_response, ip_address , http_referer , http_user_agent, Timestamp  FROM question_data INNER JOIN form_elements ON question_data.form_id = form_elements.formid ORDER BY question_data.question_id";
```

Comment: Do you know the timestamp before you run the query?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT sum(num) FROM (
    SELECT count(*) num FROM question_data GROUP BY timestamp HAVING count(*) > 1
) t
```

This is the number of records which have the same timestamp as another record.

Comment: your question doesn't work .. the error given is #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Still doesnt work !!  it returns all the timestamp /.// Not the distinct ones ...